# Training pipeline stuck on fit method in ml.net

Tags: .net, chatbot, ml.net

I am trying to build a Chatbot using ML.net. While using model array to train using SdcaMaximumEntropy algorithm to train the model, it got stuck in particular line of code. Here is the console application code,

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;

namespace mlConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static MLContext mlContext = new MLContext(seed: 0);
        static ITransformer trainedModel;
        static PredictionEngine<QnAModel, AnswerPrediction> predEngine;
        static IEstimator<ITransformer> pipeline;
        static IDataView dataView;
        public static string TrainedModelPath { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            QnAModel[] objQnAModel = new QnAModel[] {
                new QnAModel 
                { 
                    Question = "Do you ever get hurt", 
                    Answer = "I dont't have body" 
                },
                new QnAModel
                {
                    Question = "Do you ever cry",
                    Answer = "I don't have body"
                }
            };
            BuildAndTrainModel(objQnAModel);
        }

        public static void BuildAndTrainModel(QnAModel[] QnAModelCollection)
        {
            if(QnAModelCollection != null && QnAModelCollection.Count() > 0)//(!File.Exists(TrainedModelPath)) 
            {
                dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(QnAModelCollection); //mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<QnAModel>(QnAFilePath);
                pipeline = ProcessData();
                var trainingPipeline = pipeline.Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy("Label", "Fetures"))
                                        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

                trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(dataView);
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static IEstimator<ITransformer> ProcessData()
        {
            var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "Answer", outputColumnName: "Label")
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(inputColumnName:"Question", outputColumnName: "QuestionFeaturized"))
                            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Fetures", "QuestionFeaturized"))
                            .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext);
            return pipeline;
        }
    }
    public class QnAModel
    {
        [LoadColumn(0)]
        public string Question { get; set; }
        [LoadColumn(1)]
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnswerPrediction
    {
        [ColumnName("PredictedLabel")]
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have used .net core with Microsoft.ML version 1.5.2 library. It got stuck in below line of code.

> trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(dataView);

Can anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Is it giving you an error or just not responding?

Comment: Its not responding. No error given by code.

Comment: I ran the code locally and trainingPipeline.Fit(...) took around 50 secs on my machine to complete. I could make the prediction as well.  Is it stuck forever for you? My system configuration is Win 10 i7 16GB.

Comment: Somehow my program is using internet to transfer data (visible in internet column of task manager) when I call Fit(). Maybe it uses some API? 

I did not write any code that has to do anything with downloading any data.